# Want to show dynamic image in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I need to work on report in SSRS. I need to add one image for particular  customer.
The image is stored at shared location. I have path to access that image, that path i will get from one of the field from the table which is dynamic(every customer having diff path ie image), so  i want to access that image through this path which is present in field.

so anybody can help me get through this.

Thanks,

AB

Answer (score 2):

You should set  **External** the image source field, then set your expression, for example:

=string.Format("{0}/Repository/General{1}",Parameters!urlPath.Value,Fields!URL.Value)

where **Fields!URL.Value** its te url stored in your db

This article can help you

> You can include stored images in a report by specifying a URL to the image. When you use an external image in a report, the image source is set to External and the value for the image is the URL address to the image. For a report published to a report server configured for native mode, use a full or relative path. For example, http:///images/image1.jpg. For a report published to a report server configured in SharePoint integrated mode, use a fully qualified URL. For example, http:////Documents/images/image1.jpg.
>   When the report is previewed in Report Designer, preview uses the credentials of the user to display the image. When the report is run on the report server, the report server uses the unattended execution account to retrieve the image. If the unattended execution account is not specified, the image is retrieved using no credentials (anonymous user account). If either of these accounts have insufficient rights to access the image, the image will not be displayed in the report.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156482(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156482%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)