# Dynamic image in a report SSRS (Visual Studio 2013 Report Designer)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I'm building a report in the report designer from Visual Studio 2013. There is a section in the report where I need to add an image, this image has to be data-bound (I already achieved this). The only problem is, that sometime this image has a null value, so no image is been rendered. If that happen I supposed to display an image that says "Coming Soon", the only problem is this image is not in the data base, so  I have to add it from the archive directly.

My question is:

Is there a way to change how I add an image to a report during execution?
I mean, Can I have an expression to set a different source instead of a Database, either Embedded or External?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you are looking for a dynamic image; I recommend setting to `External` and in the image source field, create an expression with an `IsNothing` check against your image source path (assuming it is the path you are supplying and not the image itself).

For example: `Iif(IsNothing(Fields!ImageSource.Value), "ComingSoonImagePathOrName", Fields!ImageSource.Value)`

A similar question and solution was presented here: [Want to show dynamic image in SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100364/want-to-show-dynamic-image-in-ssrs-report)